# How to Resolve 'CompileC' Error in Xcode when Running 'npm run ios'"

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

user@NETVN inco % npx react-native run-ios
info Found Xcode workspace "ServiceProvider.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace ServiceProvider.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ServiceProvider -destination id=45211E71-A37F-4715-963D-9B687123DDAD")
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening ServiceProvider.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace ServiceProvider.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ServiceProvider -destination id=45211E71-A37F-4715-963D-9B687123DDAD

User defaults from command line:
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages
ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (79 targets)
Target 'ServiceProvider' in project 'ServiceProvider'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Pods-ServiceProvider' in project 'Pods' via file 'libPods-ServiceProvider.a' in build phase 'Link Binary'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'BEMCheckBox' in project 'Pods' via options '-lBEMCheckBox' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'BVLinearGradient' in project 'Pods' via options '-lBVLinearGradient' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-lCocoaAsyncSocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods' via options '-lDoubleConversion' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FBReactNativeSpec' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFBReactNativeSpec' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCore' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseCore' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCoreExtension' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseCoreExtension' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseCoreInternal' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseInstallations' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseInstallations' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseMessaging' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseMessaging' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Boost-iOSX' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Boost-iOSX' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Fmt' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Fmt' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Glog' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Glog' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-PeerTalk' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-RSocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-RSocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FlipperKit' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipperKit' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GoogleDataTransport' in project 'Pods' via options '-lGoogleDataTransport' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GoogleUtilities-54e75ca4' in project 'Pods' via options '-lGoogleUtilities-54e75ca4' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'PromisesObjC' in project 'Pods' via options '-lPromisesObjC' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCT-Folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCTTypeSafety' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCAsyncStorage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCAsyncStorage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCCheckbox' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCCheckbox' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCClipboard' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCClipboard' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCPicker' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCPicker' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNDateTimePicker' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNDateTimePicker' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBApp' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNFBApp' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBMessaging' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNFBMessaging' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNGestureHandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNGestureHandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNReanimated' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNReanimated' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNScreens' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNScreens' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Core' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-CoreModules' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-CoreModules' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTAnimation' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTBlob' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTLinking' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTLinking' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTNetwork' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTNetwork' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTSettings' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTSettings' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTText' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTText' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTVibration' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTVibration' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-cxxreact' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-cxxreact' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsi' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsi' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsiexecutor' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsiexecutor' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsinspector' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsinspector' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-logger' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-logger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-perflogger' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-perflogger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ReactCommon' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReactCommon' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ReactNativeGetLocation' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReactNativeGetLocation' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Yoga' in project 'Pods' via options '-lYoga' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'YogaKit' in project 'Pods' via options '-lYogaKit' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'fmt' in project 'Pods' via options '-lfmt' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'glog' in project 'Pods' via options '-lglog' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'libevent' in project 'Pods' via options '-llibevent' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'lottie-ios' in project 'Pods' via options '-llottie-ios' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'lottie-react-native' in project 'Pods' via options '-llottie-react-native' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'nanopb' in project 'Pods' via options '-lnanopb' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'react-native-config' in project 'Pods' via options '-lreact-native-config' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'react-native-date-picker' in project 'Pods' via options '-lreact-native-date-picker' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'react-native-geolocation-service' in project 'Pods' via options '-lreact-native-geolocation-service' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'react-native-maps' in project 'Pods' via options '-lreact-native-maps' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'react-native-safe-area-context' in project 'Pods' via options '-lreact-native-safe-area-context' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'react-native-webview' in project 'Pods' via options '-lreact-native-webview' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
Target 'Pods-ServiceProvider' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'BEMCheckBox' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'BVLinearGradient' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FBLazyVector' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FBReactNativeSpec' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Firebase' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCore' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCoreExtension' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FirebaseInstallations' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FirebaseMessaging' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Boost-iOSX' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Fmt' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Folly' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Glog' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-RSocket' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FlipperKit' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'GoogleDataTransport' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'GoogleUtilities-54e75ca4' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'OpenSSL-Universal' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'PromisesObjC' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RCTRequired' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNCAsyncStorage' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNCCheckbox' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNCClipboard' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNCPicker' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNDateTimePicker' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNFBApp' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNFBMessaging' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNGestureHandler' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNReanimated' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNScreens' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-CoreModules' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTActionSheet' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTImage' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTLinking' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTNetwork' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTSettings' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTText' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTVibration' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-callinvoker' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-cxxreact' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-jsi' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-jsiexecutor' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-jsinspector' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-logger' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-perflogger' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-runtimeexecutor' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'ReactCommon' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'ReactNativeGetLocation' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Yoga' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'YogaKit' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'boost' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'fmt' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'glog' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'libevent' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'lottie-ios' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'lottie-react-native' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'nanopb' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'react-native-config' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'react-native-date-picker' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'react-native-geolocation-service' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'react-native-maps' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'react-native-safe-area-context' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'react-native-webview' in project 'Pods'
Target 'react-native-webview' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods'
Target 'react-native-safe-area-context' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RCTRequired' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'ReactCommon' in project 'Pods'
Target 'react-native-maps' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods'
Target 'react-native-geolocation-service' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React' in project 'Pods'
Target 'react-native-date-picker' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods'
Target 'react-native-config' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods'
Target 'lottie-react-native' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'lottie-ios' in project 'Pods'
Target 'lottie-ios' in project 'Pods' (no dependencies)
Target 'ReactNativeGetLocation' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods'
Target 'React' in project 'Pods'GatherProvisioningInputs

CreateBuildDescription

ClangStatCache /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang-stat-cache /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.0.sdk /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator17.0-21A326-9f995cea1212cde75317d7d3cd2045e2.sdkstatcache
cd /Users/user/Desktop/inco/ios
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang-stat-cache /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.0.sdk -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator17.0-21A326-9f995cea1212cde75317d7d3cd2045e2.sdkstatcache

/Users/user/Desktop/inco/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.0.99. (in target 'Yoga' from project 'Pods')
CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGEnums.o /Users/user/Desktop/inco/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGEnums.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Yoga' from project 'Pods')
cd /Users/user/Desktop/inco/ios/Pods
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -ivfsstatcache /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator17.0-21A326-9f995cea1212cde75317d7d3cd2045e2.sdkstatcache -target x86_64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fno-color-diagnostics -std=gnu++14 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -fmodule-name=yoga -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.0.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -index-store-path /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Index.noindex/DataStore -iquote /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Yoga-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Yoga-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Yoga-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Yoga-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga/include -I/Users/user/Desktop/inco/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -I/Users/user/Desktop/inco/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Yoga -I/Users/user/Desktop/inco/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/user/Desktop/inco/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fexceptions -Wall -Werror -std=c++1y -fPIC -fno-objc-arc -include /Users/user/Desktop/inco/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Yoga/Yoga-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGEnums.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGEnums.dia -c /Users/user/Desktop/inco/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGEnums.cpp -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGEnums.o -index-unit-output-path /Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGEnums.o

CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGConfig.o /Users/user/Desktop/inco/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGConfig.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Yoga' from project 'Pods')
cd /Users/user/Desktop/inco/ios/Pods
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -ivfsstatcache /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator17.0-21A326-9f995cea1212cde75317d7d3cd2045e2.sdkstatcache -target x86_64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fno-color-diagnostics -std=gnu++14 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -fmodule-name=yoga -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.0.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -index-store-path /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Index.noindex/DataStore -iquote /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Yoga-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Yoga-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceProvider-hkhuklamflmumjeiarxjiuhlzhtz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Yoga.o /Users/user/Desktop/inco/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Yoga' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have cocoa pods installed you need to `sudo gem install cocoapods`

1. run `cd ios`
2. run `pod install`
3. `cd ..`
4. delete build folder
5. run `react-native run-ios`
   if the error persists,
6. delete build folder again
7. open the /ios folder in x-code
8. navigate File -> Project Settings -> Build System -> change (Shared workspace settings and Per-User workspace settings): Build System -> Legacy Build System`

You should be good to go.